# Edit text focus out when submitting list in recyclerview

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-edittext, listadapter, notifydatasetchanged

I'm using EditText for search functionality. But I when type something focus on Edittext. the keyboard appears but not typing until I click again on EditText.
Note: if I comment submit code then focus works fine. here is my code.

```
    fun filterList(text: String) {
    val filterdNames = ArrayList<IRTv_model_class>()
    //looping through existing elements
    for (s in mProductArrayList) {
        //if the existing elements contains the search input
        if (s.name.lowercase(Locale.getDefault())
                .contains(text.lowercase(Locale.getDefault()))
        ) {
            //adding the element to filtered list
            filterdNames.add(s)
        }
    }
    mAdapter?.submitList(filterdNames)

}
```

the filterList() method I called on afterTextChanged method using TextWatcher.

```
  binding.etSearch.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
            filterList(s.toString())
        }
    })
```

[Screen Record](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kYOamD6y9WoGqOg7sSFJKxyMkcx-pF1Q/view?usp=sharing)